# Use column header and index values for operation

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have two dataframes which are constructed from pivot tables of an elevation profile and they look like below. The second frame is a shifted version of the first time to the right by one column

Frame 1

```
Lat          32.063102  32.063194    ...      32.124676  32.124769
Lon                                  ...                          
-100.214676    617.143    617.167    ...        681.024    680.839
-100.214583    617.316    617.331    ...        680.916    680.730
-100.214491    617.495    617.497    ...        680.802    680.609
-100.214398    617.673    617.679    ...        680.690    680.499
-100.214306    617.862    617.862    ...        680.589    680.401
```

Frame 2

```
Lat          32.063194  32.063287    ...      32.124769  0.000000 
Lon                                  ...                          
-100.214676    617.167    617.175    ...        680.839          0
-100.214583    617.331    617.337    ...        680.730          0
-100.214491    617.497    617.505    ...        680.609          0
-100.214398    617.679    617.687    ...        680.499          0
-100.214306    617.862    617.867    ...        680.401          0
```

Is it possible to use the column headers and index values for operation when I try to construct a new dataframe? For example, when I subtract the second dataframe from the first, can I use the sum of square of the respective column header and index as a denominator for every value?

I tried storing the row and column headers as separate lists but couldn't integrate them when iterating over both dataframes.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your code. Also, please explain exactly what you want to do with the row and column indices. There are many ways to use these in sum-of-squares computations and it is not clear what you mean by _denominator_ as a subtraction has no denominator. E.g., do you want the first element of your resulting matrix to be `(617.143 - 617.167) / (32.063102**2 + (-100.214676)**2 + 32.063194**2 + (-100.214676)**2)`?

Comment: The first element should be the (617.143 - 617.467)/(32.063102-32.063194). Sorry for not being complete

Answer (score 0):

You want to be able to do the computation by generic column indices (as you explained in your response to my comment). This adds an additional difficulty, since the standard behavior for computations with DataFrames (i.e. `df1 - df2` or so) is to match row and column indices. This will in your case result in NaNs and useless results.

Consequently, you will have to replace the column indices by generic ones. However, if you put the original column indices in DataFrames of the same shape as the original, you can still use those in the computation.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

"""generate example data"""
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[32.063102, 32.063194])
df1.loc[-100.214676] = [617.143, 617.167]
df1.loc[-100.214583] = [617.316, 617.331]
df1.loc[-100.214491] = [617.495, 617.497]

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=[32.063194, 0])
df2.loc[-100.214676] = [617.167, 0]
df2.loc[-100.214583] = [617.331, 0]
df2.loc[-100.214491] = [617.497, 0]

"""generate auxiliary dataframes with original column indices"""
df1i = pd.DataFrame()
df1i = df1i.append([df1.columns]*len(df1.index))
df1i.index = df1.index

df2i = pd.DataFrame()
df2i = df2i.append([df2.columns]*len(df2.index))
df2i.index = df2.index

"""replace column indices by generic ones to allow the computation by generic column index"""
df1.columns = np.arange(len(df1.columns))
df2.columns = np.arange(len(df2.columns))

"""do the computation"""
df3 = (df1 - df2) / (df1i - df2i)
print(df3)
```